no captura el iframe en angular
tengo este fragmento en un form de Angular
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="form-label"><b>*Número de tarjeta</b> </label>
                <div id="cardNumber" class="form-control"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

la vuelta es que esto es un iframe y dentro de ese cardNumber dinámicamente también se ingresa otro iframe que tiene un formulario, pero como puedo capturar los datos de ese formulario.
estuve haciendo algo asi
@ViewChild('cardNumber') cardNumberDiv!: ElementRef;
prueba(){
    // Asegúrate de que el div está presente
    console.log(this.cardNumberDiv)
    if (this.cardNumberDiv) {
      const divElement = this.cardNumberDiv.nativeElement;

      // Crear un observador para detectar cambios en el DOM
      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            const iframeElement = divElement.querySelector('iframe') as HTMLIFrameElement;
            if (iframeElement) {
              // Deja de observar cuando se encuentra el iframe
              observer.disconnect();

              // Asegúrate de que el contenido del iframe haya cargado
              iframeElement.onload = () => {
                const iframeDocument = iframeElement.contentDocument || iframeElement.contentWindow?.document;

                if (iframeDocument) {
                  // Accede al input dentro del iframe
                  const inputElement = iframeDocument.querySelector('input[name="inputName"]');
                  if (inputElement) {
                    console.log('Valor del input dentro del iframe:', inputElement);

                    // Puedes agregar un event listener si es necesario
                    inputElement.addEventListener('input', (event: any) => {
                      console.log('Nuevo valor del input:', event.target.value);
                    });
                  }
                }
              };
            }
          }
        });
      });

      // Comienza a observar el div por cambios en los hijos
      observer.observe(divElement, { childList: true });
    } else {
      console.error('No se encontró el div con id "cardNumber".');
    }
  }

pero siempre se va al else de no se encontro el div
asi lo haga con un settimeout,
esta otra funcion es la mas cercana
 prueba(){
    if (this.cardNumberDiv) {
      const divElement = this.cardNumberDiv.nativeElement;
      console.log(divElement); // Aquí deberías ver el div en la consola

      // Si es necesario, agrega un setTimeout o MutationObserver
      setTimeout(() => {
        const iframeElement = divElement.querySelector('iframe') as HTMLIFrameElement;
        console.log('Iframe encontrado:', iframeElement);
        if (iframeElement){
          const iframeDocument = iframeElement.contentDocument || iframeElement.contentWindow?.document;
          console.log('estoy ingresando aca')
          console.log(iframeDocument)
        }
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      console.error('No se encontró el div con id "cardNumber".');
    }
  }

pero me sale este error

payment-page.component.ts:113 ERROR DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at http://localhost:4200/src_app_modules_payments_payments_module_ts.js:303:94
at timer (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9529:27)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7578:171)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62936:49
at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62936:30)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7578:54)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63238:25)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7578:54)
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7380:37)
at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7655:26)

el problema es que asi sea que este en la nube, me sigue el mismo problema y no soy capaz de capturar los datos de ese formulario que se encuentra en ese iframe

No uses iframe, usa modales y listo. Por seguridad no se puede acceder fácilmente al contenido de los iframe

no es que no quiera usarlos, es como lo expone el caso, asi quiera o no quiera toca

Pues entonces te tocará usar postMessage para enviar datos entre el iframe y la web "padre"

si lo puedo hacer asi no tenga control de un iframe? osea donde esta el iframe no puedo agregarle nada, es un iframe dinamico que me adjunta a un div pero yo no tengo control alguno de ese iframe

Pues si no puedes modificar su código, nadie le puede añadir eso, y no se sirve desde exactamente la misma URL en la que te encuentras... creo que no hay manera de acceder a él, sin más. El propio error te lo está diciendo: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame". El navegador no te va a dejar hacerlo, hasta donde yo llego

DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at ...  es un tema de cors . para desarrollar/debuggear metodos de pago que por lo general requieren https y a veces una validación del origin te conviene  configurar un dominio local .dev crear un selfsigned certificate, agregarlo al store del navegador/os y ya continuar el desarrollo con 2 entornos "dev" y "produccion" donde puedas configurar el cors y testmode acorde
